# Reload/refresh page after postback. SharePoint, Visual Web Part (Sandboxed)

Tags: sharepoint-2010, postback, web-parts, sandbox

I have a visual web part (sandboxed) that visualize a form for adding sub-sites. When a sub-site is added its added in the navigation and in a DropDownlist (for delete purpose...).

My problem is that after post-back everything works fine, except i have to manually reload the page to see the new changes (both nav. and dropdownlist). Note that neither **Response.Redirect** or **UpdatePanel** will work i a sandboxed-solution.

Anyone got a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3):

When you perform a postback, your browser submits the contents of all web controls to the server. The server is *stateless* in this sense; the state of the control is actually stored in your browser. I would say your problem occurs because the web controls are not populated from SharePoint object model. Instead, the server uses the data received as the postback. Alternatively, the population might even happen, but the postback data will overwrite the contents of controls.

The solution is to refresh control data *after* the controls have been populated from the postback data. You could do this, for example, in the method *OnPreRender*. When OnPreRender is called, all the postback data has already been processed.

Try to add the following code in your webpart class.

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs args)
{
    if (this.Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        // Repopulate controls here
    }
}
```

The problem of this is, of course, that repopulation will kill the previous (postback) state of the controls. So, if you want to preserve the current value of a control (such as a dropdown selection), you must save it before repopulation and restore it manually.

To learn more about the page lifecycle in ASP.NET, see [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank for your answer! How do u populate controls? Cant find a good examples/explanation. For example i want to populate my DropDownList1, again.

Comment: See [Several Ways to populate DropDownList Controls](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article30.aspx) (specifically, under headline "Populating DropDownList control through server side code").